# Чайник остывает или не остывает?

Tags: семантика

Как так получается, что две нижеприведенные фразы фактически означают одно и то же?

- Чайник долго остывает.
- Чайник долго **не** остывает.

Comment: Похожая история - со словами "экономить время", в "Алисе в Зазеркалье".  
- И пока думаешь, что ответить, делай реверанс. Это экономит время.  
Алиса очень удивилась, но Королева внушала ей такое уважение, что спорить она не посмела. "Вернусь домой - буду делать реверанс, когда опаздываю к обеду".

Ясно, что во втором случае время как раз будет теряться.

Comment: Только для русского человека "Хрен там есть" и "Ни хрена там нет" - одно и то же понятие...

Comment: >Совершенный вид - остыть, вы читать умеете?? 
  
Я Вас раньше спросила. ))) Даже два раза.
"Остывает" - это совершенныый вид? Да или нет?

Answer (score 15):

Ничего удивительного.

Чайник долго закипает - Чайник долго не закипает.
Ребенок долго засыпает - Ребенок долго не засыпает.
Сад долго увядает - Сад долго не увядает.
и т. д.

Значения везде если не тождественны, то близки.
Значения подобных глаголов - *находиться в переходном состоянии*.
И это состояние переходное, что с "не", что без него. И если оно длится долго (подразумевается, что не вечно и событие еще не наступило), то различия вообще исчезают.

Хотя, строго говоря, если быть буквоедом, то во всех случаях мы немного подменяем объективный смысл бытовым, т. е. собственными представлениями о назначении процесса. "Долго не остывает" формально - долго не начинает остывать, "долго остывает" - начал, но долго это делает. Но на эти мелочи обычно внимания не обращают.

Comment: Я бы сказал по-другому. "Долго не остывает" - означает, что чайник очень долго не переходит в состояние "остыл", а "долго остывает" говорит о длительности самого процесса остывания.

Answer (score 7):

"Чайник долго остывает" = чайник долго становится холодным.
"Чайник долго не остывает" = чайник долго остаётся горячим.

И во всех подобных случаях – то же самое. Все до безобразия просто.

Comment: Вы утверждаете: "Чайник долго остывает" = чайник долго не становится холодным". Из этого следует: остывать - это не становиться холодным?

Comment: Нет. Все дело в нашем отношении к предмету.

"Возьми этот термос. В нем чай долго НЕ остывает." Без НЕ ну никак не скажешь. Нам надо, чтобы НЕ остывал.

Comment: Мотор перегрелся... Теперь мы опоздаем, потому что двигатель долго остывает. (Здесь без НЕ, т.к. нам надо, чтоб поскорее остыл)

Comment: Это лингвистическая задача, и решать ее надо строго по форме. (Чайник долго) остывает" = (чайник долго) не становится холодным. Уже здесь логическая ошибка: исключаем  первую общую часть и получаем противоречие (остывает = не становится холодным).

Comment: Это лингвистическая задача, и решать её надо лингвистически! А не формально логически. И формальные противоречия смущать не должны.
Мы говорим "долго не остывает", когда нам нужно, чтобы он был горячим. Мы говорим " долго остывает" в противоположном случае – когда хотим, чтоб остыл.

Comment: Именно формальные противоречия и смущают, и именно они явились предметом обсуждения. Грамматика - наука формальная, поэтому логика должна в ней присутствовать.

Answer (score 6):

Я люблю задавать похожий вопрос:
Слова "жадный" и "скупой" - синонимы. А могут они стать антонимами?

Ответ. Думаю, да. Например: "Жадный на ласку" - "Скупой на ласку".
Наверное, дело в том, что эти синонимы не полные. Вот этот-то "зазор смыслов" и можно "растянуть" до их противоположности.

Comment: Возражу. Жадный и скупой "на ласку" - одно и то же. Человек, который редко кого приласкает. А вот тот, кто сам любит **приласкаться** - "жаден до ласки". Давайте сравним и эти выражения!
Любит принимать ласки (ж. до л.)- не любит дарить ласки (с. на л.). Один жаден, другой скуп - все то же самое со смыслом! Себялюбие в обоих случаях...

Comment: У С. И. Ожегова "скупой" идёт как второе значение слова "жадный". Между тем в народном понимании - "жадный" - это тот, кто тащит к себе всё без разбору, а "скупой" - тот, кто не любит отдавать никому то, что имеет. Смысловое значение обоих слов не совпадает: жадный, как правило, и скупой, но скупой (теоретически) может и не быть жадным. Так что Плюшкин - жадный (и скупой), а Царь Кощей - (только) скупой. У жадного (предприимчивого) отца могут быть разного рода дети: жадные (предприимчивые), скупые (не предприимчивые) м моты.

Answer (score 5):

*Величина остается постоянной* и *величина   меняется* — это две противоположные ситуации. Добавляем слово «долго». Получается: *величина долго остается постоянной* и *величина долго меняется*, и это уже одно и то же. Похоже на философский закон единства и борьбы противоположностей в действии.

Теперь переходим к чайнику. *Чайник долго не остывает* (сохраняет температуру) то же, что *чайник долго остывает* (очень медленно меняет температуру). Фраза *чайник долго остывает* имеет разговорный характер, лучше сказать: *медленно остывает*. С нагревающимся чайником примерно такая же ситуация. А вот *чайник закипающий*... Фраза *чайник долго закипает* (т.е. долго начинает кипеть) носит совсем разговорный (бытовой) характер.

Мне кажется, что и весь лингвистический парадокс в целом основан именно на неточности бытовой речи.

*Остывать* (стынуть) — *остывает* (стынет); а *остыть* — *остынет*.

ОТВЕТ. Можно много спорить о правильности различных выражений, но ведь речь шла о конкретном парадоксе: предложение «Чайник долго остывает»" при добавлении частицы ***не*** не меняет своего значения, как это следовало бы ожидать. Поэтому анализировать здесь правомерно только форму глагола  *остывать*, представленную в предложениях.

Answer (score 4):

Все гораздо проще, и объяснять надо тоже проще. 
 Дело тут в том, что "мнимо" используется не один и тот же глагол, а два: остыть и остывать. Первый – совершенного вида, второй – несовершенного.

"Долго не остывает" – тут как бы форма глагола "остыть" (совершенный вид, он указывает на результат, законченность и так далее), то есть чайник долго не приходит в какое-то остывшее СОСТОЯНИЕ, долго нет РЕЗУЛЬТАТА.

"Долго остывает" – тут форма глагола "остывать" (несовершенный вид, он указывает на процесс, продолжительность), то есть чайник долго находится в ПРОЦЕССЕ остывания.

Забавно, что фразу "долго не остывает" можно понять и в противоположном смысле. Так же, например, как можно сказать "он долго не просит" о человеке, который привык брать свое без лишних уговоров. Если такой смысл вкладывать, то тут тоже будет форма глагола "остывать" с логичным противопоставлением с "не" и без "не". Хотя тут это достигается окольным путем.

В общем, дело тут в том, что форма "остывает" подсознательно воспринимается нами производной и от "остывать", и от "остыть".

P.S.
Переформулировал ответ. "Остывает" – это, конечно, несовершенный вид, н.ф. – "остывать". Но вот в выражении "долго не остывает" появляется некий системный эффект, и глагол "остывает" воспринимается как форма глагола "остыть".

Согласен с Дерзким. Уверен, что это связано с преобразованием выражения "долго не может остыть": модальный глагол "может" опускается, аналитическая структура пропадает, на смену ей приходит словоизменение (потому что инфинитив идет после модальных слов обычно, а без него используются личные формы). Пусть и не совсем корректное словоизменение, но тем не менее.

Comment: Проще не получилось. Что делает? - не остывает. А вы говорите -  вид совершенный.

Comment: Вот тут-то и кроется ошибка! Вместо *долго не остывает* следует говорить : **долго не может остыть**))) 
Пример с другой парой глаголов абсолютно одинакового написания, но с разным ударением :  
осЫпать (сов. вид - что сделать?)  
осыпАть (несов. вид - что делать?)  
Клен долго не может осЫпаться (что сделать?)  
Клен долго осыпАется (что делает?)  
Та же самая ситуация. Как Вы считаете, Ларf?

Comment: Причем здесь "ошибка Пересвета"?? Эта ошибка в выражении, надо говорить - "чайник долго не может остыть", вот и все. Надеюсь, Дерзкого груманта никто не может заподозрить в нечестном ведении форумных игр? Я не скрываюсь за чужими никами, они у меня свои и вполне заслуженные, см. профиль Дерзкий и grumant. А вот кое у кого рыльце в пушку...  
Кстати, я писал свой коммент для Ларf.

Comment: >Надеюсь, Дерзкого груманта никто не может заподозрить в нечестном ведении форумных игр?    
  
И не надейтесь. Уже заподозрила.  
Я Вас "русским по белому" спросила, Вы правда считаете "остывает" совершенном видом? А Вы опять про свои геморрои в профиле.  
  
Или это по-Вашему "честная игра"?

Comment: Товарисч, все геморрррррои - у вас с бегемотусом)))  
Совершенный вид - остыть, вы читать умеете?? Долго не может остыть - правильное выражение, с глаголом в сов. виде. Долго остывает/не остывает - несов. вид. Удовлетворены, уважаемая подозрительная иринаGLA?  
**Вот тут-то и кроется ошибка** - я это выше написал, перечтите и поймите смысл правильно.

Comment: >Согласен с Дерзким.   
  
Приятно быть в согласии с собой. 
Однако Вы явно переоценили действенность подобного приема. 
Ерунда - она и в Африке ерунда.  
С какой стати чайник должен ***мочь*** "остывать"? По мне так он должен держать тепло как можно дольше. Тогда уж "может долго не остывать".

Comment: >А почему не должен?  

Потому что. Последуйте своему совету: прочитайте, что написано.

>Модальный глагол. Служебное слово.  

Да. Третье лицо единственного числа. Из пяти букв. Два слога. Рифмуется с рожей.  
Какие еще сведения о глаголе "может" Вас интересуют? 

>Нюансы с теплом, температурой – это все тут не к месту. Такие мелочи в языке при бытовом общении не отображаются.  

"У меня для Вас плохая новость". 
Вы не просто забыли с чего, Вы еще и ерунду несете даже если забыть про контекст.
Вполне себе отображаются. Это в языке голованов одна модальность (АБС). А в русском - есть выбор.

Comment: >Смысл не одинаковый.  
  
С точностью до малозначимых на бытовом уровне оттенков смысла. Я об этом говорил. В первом приближении - совпадает. 
Писал еще в июле. Читали?

>Я уже объяснил  
  
А я с Вами не согласился. После этого Вы начали истерику и на этом обсуждение закончилось. Хотите вернуться с исходному?
Начните с того, что перечитайте - и попробуйте опровергнуть меня, или по крайней мере не нойте, что я Ваши в грош не ставлю.

Answer (score 2):

"Чайник долго не остывает" - это не русская фраза, она бессмысленна. Правильно, содержательно - надо говорить: "Чайник долго остывает", и каждому понятно, о чём идёт речь: когда чайник большой, объёмный, он остывает долго. Но вот - как перевести на русский язык фразу: "Чайник долго не остывает"? Что хочет сказать человек, произносящий эту фразу? "...долгое время не может остыть"? Но это по смыслу не равносильно "...долго не остывает". Сапоги всмятку. В любом случае ответ сведётся к фразе: "Чайник долго остывает", и тогда отрицательной фразе нет положительного ответа, она - набор слов, пустое множество, летающие слоны. "Чайник долго не может остыть" (или: "...остывать") - это понятные фразы, но у них и смысл разный. Во всяком случае, ни та, ни другая никак по смыслу не связаны с исходной отрицательной фразой (её и отрицательной-то нельзя назвать, потому что она бессмысленна). "Чайник остывает" - истина, "Чайник не остывает" - ложь, а "долго" это лишь усилительное наречие

Answer (score 2):

Здесь много очень интересных мнений, рассуждений, но осмелюсь добавить и свою версию анализируемых примеров. Дело в том, что абсолютно все фразы существуют не сами по себе, а являются порождением тех или иных коммуникативных ситуаций, в которых на формирование звуковой материализации произнесённой фразы влияют не только лексико-грамматические правила языка, но и прямые или косвенные намерения говорящего, а также его багаж предварительных знаний и эмоций по отношению в высказываемому. То есть в высказывании от человека к человеку всегда открыто или скрыто присутствует диктумно-модусное соотношение, то есть определённая дозированность: а) констатации факта и б)отношения к этому факту.
  С этой точки зрения пример "Чайник долго остывает" выдаёт констатацию факта о постоянных качествах чайника, которые его характеризуют изначально и которые от него ОЖИДАЮТСЯ в применении всегда и везде. Такое построение предложения уместно в рекламном тексте об этом чайнике и воспримается как положительное, "выигрышное" описание качества в сравнении с другим таким же предметом другого производителя.
Высказывание "Чайник долго не остывает" наоборот обнажает модусную часть, а именно, реальность, противоположную тому, что ожидает говорящий, то есть НЕОЖИДАЕМОЕ. Особенно сильно это значение чувствуется, когда мы данное предложение переводим в прошедшее время: "Чайник долго не остывал". Говорящий думал, ожидал, что чайник быстрее остынет, но он не остывал ВОПРЕКИ ОЖИДАНИЯМ. Смысл, то есть ДИКТУМ передаваемого высказывания в обоих случаях одинаков, что и заводит в заблуждение при анализе, однако в "Чайник долго остывает" есть модусность "ожидания" (то есть происходит так, как и должно быть), а в "Чайник долго не остывал" действие описывается с модусом  "вопреки ожиданиям" говорящего.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя у вопроса тег «семантика», предполагающий различные толкования слов/сл-ий/фраз и размышления на темы разговорной/бытовой речи, переносных смыслов и проч., вот формальный подход к вопросу:

1. Во фразах автора исп-ся глагол «остывает» (нач. ф. остывать, несов. вид). След-но, все рассуждения с исп-ем глагола «остыть» (сов. вид) необх. сразу отбросить.
2. Необх. оперировать не семантическими свойствами глагола, а его признаками.
3. Остывать -- находиться в процессе остывания. Не остывать -- не находиться в процессе остывания. След-но, с формальной точки зрения фразы автора *не* означают одно и то же.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте сначала посмотрим, что могут описывать более общие(пространные) предложения (скелеты):

1. Чайник остывает.
2. Чайник не остывает.

1-ое предложение может описывать как минимум две ситуации:

- Чайник остывает прямо сейчас. // Чайник начал остывать, но не закончил (презент континиус, наличие процесса)
- Чайник окончательно остывает. // Чайник закончил остывать (презент перфект, наличие результата)

2-ое предложение может описывать как минимум две ситуации:

- Чайник всё никак не остывает (остынет). // Начал, но не закончил остывание. (Отрицается наличие результата (презент перфект). Однако подчеркивается наличие процесса)
- Чайник уже не остывает. // Закончил остывание, хотя не обязательно остыл. (Отрицается наличие процесса (презент континиус). Однако подчеркивается наличие некоторого результата)

Мы видим, что различные временные/модальные наречия меняют смысл глагола несовершенного вида "остывает" в диапазоне от продолжительного действия (континиус) до действия характеризующегося некоторым результатом (перфект).

Теперь давайте посмотрим что меняет появление наречия "долго":

- Чайник долго (всё никак) не остывает. // Здесь "долго" используется в значении "всё никак". В значении характеризующим наличие результата!
- Чайник долго (длительно) остывает. // Здесь "долго" используется в значении "длительно". В значении характеризующим процесс!

Итого, мы воспринимаем смысл этих фраз одинаковым, по причине того что глагол совершенного вида "остывает" используется в первой фразе для характеристики действия как процесса (континиус время),
а во второй фразе для характериситики действия как законченного и имеющего результат (перфектное время). (Сравните: "Вася уходит из дома." и "Вася уходит из дома прямо сейчас.").
Но что придает одному и тому же глаголу "остывает" разные "временные модальности"? Ответ: разные значения наречия "долго". В первом случае значение "всё никак", а во втором "длительно".
И конечно все эти значения диктуются контекстом ситуации (бытовым смыслом). Есть и другие контексты, которые могут изменить смысл этих предложений на противоположный.
Я лишь описал те, в рамках которых обе фразы имеют тождественные смыслы.