# Открыть Америку

Tags: лексика, фразеология

Читаю в словарях:
*"Открыть Америку"* - говорить, объявлять о том, что всем давно известно; делать открытия, на самом деле давно и всем известные, и громко заявлять об этом.

Тогда как мне следует выразиться?

- в соответствии с толкованиями словарей:
  *"Оказалось, я открыла Америку: все и так об этом знали."*
- Так бы написала я без словаря, но, выходит, неверно:
  *"Оказалось, Америку я не открыла: все и так об этом знали."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [Фразеологическому словарю русского языка](http://enc-dic.com/russian_phrase/Otkryvat-ameriku-539.html) такое употребление возможно.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите отнести данное выражение к себе, то лучше сначала изложить свои несбывшиеся надежды, а затем выразить этими словами результат: 
"*Оказалось, что Америки я (этим) **не** открыла*." (без добавлений).

Классический же случай употребления - выражение скептицизма по поводу чужих "прозрений": `"Тоже мне, открыл Америку!"` (это и так все знают)

Comment: Любопытно, но "Оказалось, что этим я открыла Америку." - судя по словарям, даже более корректно. Но для меня Ваш вариант звучит привычней.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что в словарях препарировали едва ли не единственное устойчивое выражение "Открыл Америку!" и предложили в качестве примера. Думаю, что все остальные варианты являются авторскими (по аналогии с "собака порылась"). В быту это выражение не используется столь свободно, как "изобрести велосипед", а принадлежит той самой подзабытой  реплике.

Answer (score 1):

*Открыть Америку* — это фразеологизм ([см.](http://phraseologiya.academic.ru/770/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83) в словаре). Мне кажется, выражение *не открыть Америку* тоже имеет право на существование, потому что имеет значение *не сообщать что-либо новое*. Мы ведь можем добавлять частицу НЕ к такому фразеологизму, как, например, *хватать звезд с неба*.

Answer (score 1):

Катя, оба варианта совершенно верны. И что самое интересное, почти тождественны по смыслу. Так бывает.

Дело в том, что словари приводят переносное значение, когда-то сугубо ироничное, приобретшее противоположный смысл, но ставшее основным.

Но и прямое значение "сделать реальное открытие" сохранилось.

Вот вам простенькая аналогия.
Вы можете с соответствующей интонацией сказать "Гениально!", высмеивая чью-то глупость. А можете и "не гениально" - тогда это будет прямолинейно, но однозначно.

Так и тут. Контекст дает достаточно оснований понять, что вы не говорите о реальном открытии чего-то, поэтому и "открыть Америку" и "не открыть Америки" здесь означают ровно одно и тоже. Словари тому не противоречат. Выбор за Вами, вариант без "не" мне кажется более экспрессивным.

В других же подобных случаях, смотрите по обстоятельствам, могут ди вас неправильно понять, если есть сомнения, то вариант с "не" будет предпочтительным, он не допускает двух толкований. Коли он вам больше нравится, так на нем и останавливайтесь ради однозначности.

посмотрите еще примеры выражений эквивалентных с "не" и без "не". Правда, они на другом принципе построены, но все же любопытны.

[Чайник остывает или не остывает?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6545)